# Binding redirects

Tags: c#, binding, redirect

Where is the best place to find information on binding redirects?  or maybe just a basic explanation of where you put these redirects within a project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where you put it can only be configuration. Find details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fc472t2(vs.71).aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Why not start from the [beginning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fc472t2(VS.80).aspx)?

after understood what it does, you will end up with something like:

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="myAssembly"
                              publicKeyToken="32ab4ba45e0a69a1"
                              culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0"
                             newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
         </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: which file do you put this in?

Comment: you can do app.config or machine.config. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ash1ksb(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

There are several [configuration files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f6988ab.aspx) that can include binding redirects. Another option besides the configuration files is to use the [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) event to decide on redirects at run time. I've included some sample code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460271/how-to-use-assembly-binding-redirection-to-ignore-revision-and-build-numbers/2344624#2344624).